# Added View in Ionic shows up plain white

Tags: javascript, android, html, ionic-framework, ionic2

I wanted to add a Login-Screen to my Ionic-App. But somehow the App just goes white when the urlRouterProvider points to the specified path. At the moment it looks like this:

login.html (template)

```
<ion-view view-title="login">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Username</span>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Password</span>
      <input type="password">
    </label>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Fairly simple, just to input fields.

the app.js containts this:

```
  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

    .state('dash.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'login': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
          controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash/login');
```

Yes, the dash view should be parent of the login. 
Controller exists, but has no functionality at this moment:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {})
```

I am very new, but according to the most online documentations this should already work! I added a new view, created the state according to it, then pointed the urlRouterProvider to it, which works since the start screen of the app is plain white at the moment with the navbar at the top, added the empty controller and that's it.

There is no service yet and I didn't change the index.html. The App is a Tab-based template of Ionic, with the tabs.html looking like this:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Home" icon-off="ion-home" icon-on="ion-home" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Kalender Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Kalender" icon-off="ion-calendar" icon-on="ion-calendar" href="#/tab/chats">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Fangbuch Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Fangbuch" icon-off="ion-folder" icon-on="ion-folder" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


</ion-tabs>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a view that corresponds with your login screen.  In your index.html, do you see where it says `<ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>`?  Notice the name of that view corresponds with the view's name in your ui-router state:

```
.state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

With that being said, here's a pen I found that should help you in the right direction - https://codepen.io/ionic/pen/CbBsA

Comment: My index.html just contains this: <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

Comment: Sorry I meant your tabs.html, where it says `name="tab-dash"`